# Echo values from custom field outside loop php

Tags: custom-field, loop

I create custom field type select

[image]

Need display `values` from custom field outside `<?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>` like [bootstrap tabs](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/navs/#tabs).

Code 1:

```
<?php
            global $wp_query;
            $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
            var_dump($postid);
            echo get_post_meta($postid, 'employee_category', true); 
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

return - `int(269)` - id page.

Code 2:

```
<?php
        $value = get_field( "employee_category" );
        if( $value ) {
            echo $value;
        } else {
            echo 'empty';
        }
        ?>
```

return - `empty`.

Code 2 inside loop work correctly.

How display values outside loop?

**UPD**

Need to display all categorys.

This code

```
<?php
            global $wp_query;
            $postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
            $value = get_field( "employee_category", 269 );
            var_dump($value);
            if( $value ) {
                echo $value;
            } else {
                echo 'empty';
            }
            wp_reset_query();
        ?>
```

return `null`

Comment: This field belongs to a post or page? you can just try to do `global $post` on the top of your code, and get the `$post->ID`. That should work for you. If don't please elaborate your question.

Comment: This field belongs to page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs d-flex justify-content-center flex-wrap team-navs">
                <?php $loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'employee', 'post_status'=>'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) ); ?>
                <?php
                $counter = 0;
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    $counter++;
                    $value = get_field( "employee_category" );
                    ?>
                    <li class="nav-item post-<?php the_ID(); ?> <?=($counter == 1) ? 'active' : ''?>">
                        <a class="nav-link" role="tab" href="#<?php echo $value; ?>" aria-controls="home" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"><?php echo $value; ?></a>
                    </li>
                <?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
            </ul>
```

This code display category. But at the same time its dublicates tabs, if if there is post of the same category. And need to make switching tabs...

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass `$postid` to your `get_field` function.

```
<?php
    $value = get_field( "employee_category", $postid );
    if( $value ) {
        echo $value;
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
?>
```

See docs: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: thanks for help, but not working outside loop

Answer (score 1):

You can access a custom field by supplying the post ID in the second arguement.

```
get_field($selector, [$post_id]);
```

So in your case you would do the following:

```
$value = get_field( "employee_category", $postid );
```

You can view the full documentation here: https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field/

Comment: thanks for help, but not working outside loop

Comment: Are you getting the postid beforehand, try replacing $postid with 269. So $value = get_field( "employee_category", 269 );

Comment: yes, i make this, but it return `null`. i update my question

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to echo out all of the choices for that ACF select field you need to use `get_field_object('employee_category')`not `get_field()`

```
<?php
    $value = get_field_object("employee_category");
    if( $value['choices'] ) {
        echo $value['choices'];
    } else {
        echo 'empty';
    }
?>
```

https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/get_field_object/

Comment: thank you for version, but not working for me